# how can i add a function to json object which has __type attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am sending an object that i generated within a class from the server as a result of web service call.

[image]

it is returning with __type and it's other attributes from server.

[image]

I want to add some function to this object to call from everywhere easly in my files.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks...

Comment: just fyi, the `contentType` property in `.ajax()` does only affect data you are `sending` over the wire. For receiving, `dataType` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I get you right, you want to add a `function()` to the returned object. You can't add a function serverside, since you are not allowed to transfer executable javascript code within a `JSON object`.

So you would have to add a method/property to that object after your client has created your javascript object. like

```
success: function(data){
   data.my_new_method = function(){
      // yay!
   }
},
```

Comment: But i want to add it before ajax to access in every where of my code.

Comment: @uzuay95: I'm not aware of any way to include a `function()` into a JSON notation. 99% it's not possible.